# Смена xtype по клику

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

На панели отрисовывается пользовательский xtype со списком новостей. Как сделать так что бы при нажатии на одну из новостей на месте существующего xtype со списком выводился другой xtype на котором  информация о выбранной новости?